# Pandas Category sub-group 0 counts

Tags: python, pandas

I'm new to Pandas, and trying to generate a table of subgroup counts maintaining the category order, and showing zero counts. It's a simple category with 4 options.

Without grouping it works as expected, but with grouping it isn't displaying zero counts (see last group).

In [21]:

```
df2['Call_cat'] = df2['Group_INV'].astype('category')
counts = df2['Call_cat'].value_counts(dropna=True, sort=False)
counts
```

Out[21]:

```
1.0    35773
2.0      290
3.0     8680
4.0    18867
Name: Call_cat, dtype: int64
```

In [22]:

grouped = df2.groupby('Z1')['Call_cat'].value_counts(dropna=True, sort=False)
grouped

Out[22]:

```
Z1    Call_cat
ZLZO  1.0         2961
      2.0           24
      3.0          476
      4.0         1221
ZZRE  1.0          307
      2.0            2
      3.0          152
      4.0          197
ZZMB  1.0          904
      3.0          198
      4.0          906
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a `MultiIndex` from all combinations of values of two grouping columns and reindex the groupby result with this multiindex. Then fill NaN values with zeros.

```
import pandas as pd
# example data
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':list('xxxyyy'), 'b':[1,2,3,1,2,2]})
#    a  b
# 0  x  1
# 1  x  2
# 2  x  3
# 3  y  1
# 4  y  2
# 5  y  2

multi_index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df.a.unique(), df.b.unique()], 
                                         names=['a', 'b'])\
                           .sort_values()
df.groupby(['a','b']).size().reindex(multi_index).fillna(0).astype(int)
```

This produces

```
a  b
x  1    1
   2    1
   3    1
y  1    1
   2    2
   3    0
```